# Disable displayName in production

Tags: create-react-app, styled-components

I'm using `styled-components` 4.0 in a CRA 2.0 app. By default, the component name is displayed in the DOM like this

```
<button class="Button-asdf123 asdf123" />
```

instead of just

```
<button class="asdf123" />
```

It's very helpful in development. I wonder though, how do I disable the added component name to the class in production environment, as it's redundant?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [styled components doc](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging), you should be able to control it through the options of the babel plugin

https://github.com/styled-components/babel-plugin-styled-components

Basically your webpack config for the production build should look like this

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-styled-components",
      {
        "displayName": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Since you're using CRA, you probably don't have access to your webpack config though, unless you eject (if I remember correctly)

If you are using the styled components macro, you should be able to do this without ejecting by putting this configuration in one of the files [indicated here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#experimental-config)